# rails form outputs a score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which takes in loads of data here is an example of the form:

```
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <% if @profile.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this profile from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @profile.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<form>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email">Small bio about yourself</label>
    <%= f.text_area :bio, :class => "form-control", :id => "Email", :rows => "3",
      :placeholder => "bio here"%>
  </div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :portfolios do |portfolio| %>
      <%= render partial: 'partials/portfolio_fields', :f => portfolio  %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add image', f, :portfolios %>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
<% end %>
```

the profile(scaffolded) belongs to a user created by devise. What I'm trying to do is for example if the user fills his bio, he gets a score (+2 points) and for each portfolio he adds he gets more (+5 points) and at the end of the form the score is calculated.

something like this

```
if bio.empty?
 score = 3
else
 score = 0
end
```

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the score to the user as he fills in the info (ex: bio, portfolios) etc, then you need to look at implementing in the client side using javascript.

But if you want to save it to the `profiles` table upon form submission and display that info later to the user, then you can implement it through callbacks on the `Profile` model as follows:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  before_save :assign_score

  protected
  def assign_score
    score = self.score || 0
    score += 3 if self.changes.include?(:bio) and self.bio.present?
    score += 5 if self.portfolios.present?

    self.score = score
  end
end
```

The problem with this approach, is that every time you update the `profile` record, you need to make sure that you are not double calculating by storing other info like bio_calculated, etc. Otherwise, you keep adding the score for `bio` and `portfolios` etc.

Or if you want to just display the score, which is computed dynamically, you could define a custom method in your `Profile` model as follows:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def score
   score = 0
   score += 3 if self.bio.present?
   score += 5 * self.portfolios.count
   score # this last line is optional, as ruby automatically returns the last evaluated value, but just added for explicity
  end
end
```

Comment: What i forgot to add to the source code above is that "score" is a column where the score needs to get saved. I tried self.score but it does not work?

Comment: how could i store this in a column in the profile table called score?

Comment: Are you getting any error while trying to use the first approach of using `before_save :assign_score`? If not try to either add `puts` statements or debugger within the `assign_score` method and walk through the steps.